# Functions that call each other in a module in OCaml

Tags: recursion, module, call, ocaml

I have a question about ocaml, i'm a beginner :-)

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do : (I know this is non-sense but it's not my real code, it's just an example)

```
let func a b = a
let func2 a b = b

let func_a a b =
    if b < 0 then
       func_b b a
    else
       func a b

let func_b a b =
    if a < 0 then
       func2 a b
    else
       func_a b a
```

The problem is:
`Unbound value func_b in the first "if" in func_a...`

If anyone could help?

**Edit:** I understand why this is unbound, but I dont know how to fix it.

Thanks a lot!

Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword is [mutually recursive functions](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~dmatusze/resources/ocaml/ocaml.html#Mutually%20recursive%20functions):

```
let func a b = a
let func2 a b = b

let rec func_a a b =
    if b < 0 then
       func_b b a
    else
       func a b

and func_b a b =
    if a < 0 then
       func2 a b
    else
       func_a b a
```